# There is a group made of 25 people made of 10 men and 15 women....

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

There is a group made of $25$ people made of $10$ men and $15$ women. How many
committees of $2$ men and $3$ women ($5$ people total) can be chosen from this
group?

I know you are supposed to use some kind of $(^n_k)$ type calculation but this seems so trivial... wouldn't you just have $5$ committees ? So wouldn't there be $2^5*3^5 = 7776$

Comment: No answer is not $7776$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From 10 men, they choose 2, so that's exactly $\binom{10}{2}$ and from 15 women, they choose 3, so that's exactly $\binom{15}{3}$ possibilities. You can multiply them for the final answer(they are independent events).

The final answer is $45 \cdot 455$.

Comment: Ohhh they are independent. so $\frac{15!}{(12!*3!)} * \frac{10!}{(8!*2!)}$

Comment: Yeah, that is the correct formula

Comment: You can obtain the binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{k}$ by typing \binom{n}{k} between dollar signs.

Comment: Except the curly braces around n and k are not needed if they are only a single character like the number 5.  So if you wanted 10 choose 5 displayed for example, you would put the curly braces around the 10 but they are not needed around the 5.  So for example, \binom {10} 5 between dollar signs.  You could do \binom {10} {5} but it wastes characters and if your comment is very long like over the limit or close to it, these few characters can make a significant difference.

Comment: You can also just do (^n_k) to get $(^n_k)$ less typing ;)

Answer (score 1):

$5$ because there are only $5$ pair of men available and $5$ triples of women available.

Comment: I think that is not correct, since one pair is different from the other if at least one member is other.

Comment: The question asked is not how many different committees, it is how many committees.  Bad wording if you meant something else.  One "missing" word changes my answer.

Comment: I don't know, maybe the one who asked it knows what is the correct wording, I understood it in an other way.

Comment: No, Atvin is correct, the wording is correct. See David I thought what you thought at first, but I think it is implying what Atvin has said

Comment: The task can be asked in this way too: In how many ways you can choose $2$ from $10$, and $3$ from $15$? And that is exactly the combination without repetition.

Comment: As worded, my answer of 5 is correct.  The person who asked the question didn't say how many different committees (with replacement) so I did not assume that and answered as worded.  For example, after you select committee # 1, there are only 20 people left to choose from, otherwise you are counting the same people multiple times in multiple committees.

Comment: "How many committees of 2 men and 3 women (5 people total) can be chosen from this group?" I think is implying how many different combinations...If it isn't then you are most definitely correct but that is how my teacher worded it so I guess I'll have to ask him. I'm almost certain he wouldn't give us something so trivial though, but who knows. Thanks anyways for the help David

Comment: Tell your teacher if he meant different possible committees that he has to state that, otherwise the trivial answer of 5 is correct.

Comment: I will do that for sure.

Comment: If he was my teacher I would answer 5 and if he marked it wrong I would complain.  If he still didn't give me full credit then I would escalate it to a higher authority to expose his possible incompetence in properly wording questions.  Then maybe he will think twice about the next time he asks a similar type question.  Too many people (even on this site) do not word questions properly/clearly, thus leaving the "door open" for multiple interpretations, each of which might be argued as "correct" as was the case here.  Without clarification, multiple interpretations are possible and likely.

Comment: So what did your teacher say about the questionable wording?  Just because the question has the word chosen in it doesn't mean you automatically use something like $\binom {10} 2$ * $\binom {15} 3$.

Comment: He paused for about a good 10 seconds, then looked at the way I did it (not the trivial way) and said I did it correctly. So I just said well hell with it, and turned it in. I think you are correct that he worded it incorrectly but he is foreign so maybe he didn't realize it.

Comment: It is not that he worded it incorrectly, he worded it in a way that is open for multiple interpretations so it is ambiguous.  That alone opens up room for multiple "correct" answers if someone argues that the question was ambiguous (which it is).  Ask him after you choose the first committee of 5, there are only 20 people remaining to chose from.  Where does it say in his question that the 5 people already chosen can go back into the "pool" of possible choices?  That is where the problem with the wording comes in.

Comment: Also he didn't ask for different committees so if the chosen people can go back into the pool, I can keep choosing until the end of time and get way more than $20,000$ or so choices.  Even if he did say different he would have to define what he means by that such as if they all had letters assigned to them from A thru Y ($25$ of them), how many choices are possible such that each committee of $5$ chosen has a unique combination of $5$ letters vs. every other chosen committee of $5$.  He would also have to state if order is important or not such as is ABCDE considered different than ACEBD.